# Em termos de experiência do usuário há impacto em remover acentuações e caracteres especiais de um URL?

Tags: url, ux

Gostaria de saber se existe algum motivo para remover caracteres especiais de uma URL. Por exemplo, o URL abaixo (aqui do SOpt):

> pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-**é**-callback

Possui, evidentemente, um caractere especial (`é`). Considero caractere especial todo aquele que **não** faz parte da tabela ASCII, caracteres esses que *geralmente* são removidos nessa parte da URL que alguns costumam chamar de "*slug*".

Ao contrário de sites como o StackOverflow, alguns outros parecem preferir por "remover a acentuação" ou simplesmente remover o caractere por completo, de modo a transformar, por exemplo, o endereço anterior em algo como:

- pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-e-callback
- pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-callback

Gostaria saber se há alguma motivação para remover esses caracteres. Está ligado à experiência do usuário? Quais os impactos que posso causar ao removê-los ou ao mantê-los?

Ao que me parece, essa questão está mais voltada ao âmbito da experiência do usuário porque vejo muitos sites (como o próprio SO) manterem acentos e caracteres especiais no URL, enquanto outros optam pela remoção. Assim, como alguns fazem e outros não, creio que não haja "limitação tecnológica" ou um problema de fato em utilizá-los.

Se houver alguma "limitação tecnológica" que motive a remoção desses caracteres (indo além do campo da experiência do usuário), também gostaria de saber.

Comment: Sou novo na área, mas acredito que no passado havia problemas ao nomear arquivos com caracteres especiais. Apesar do navegador mostrar o caracter especial, bor baixo dos panos a URL é codificada e é enviado "%C3%A9" no lugar do "é", antigamente isso não ocorria. Mesmo hoje se copiar a URL receberá codificada. Também pode ter problemas se o charset não for configurado corretamente, o mesmo problema que ocorre quando você vê uma interrogação (?) no lugar dos acentos, aí, em vez de salvar um arquivo "é-[...]", é salvo "?-[...]". Usar não é um problema em si, mas remover pode prevenir um ou outro

Comment: Provavelmente porque essa decisão de trocar `á` por `a` ou remover é devido a codificação, `á` será codificado como `%E1` e em UTF-8 será `%C3%A1`, então ficará o problema de resolver isso a todo momento, leve em consideração que parte da URL pode ser usado na consulta, de um documento ou banco, sendo banco dependendo da codificação outro exemplo que serão equivalentes seria `ß` e `ss`, o que poderia conflitar com outras coisas, em um site "internacional" (que use mais de um idioma) ...

Comment: .... não trabalhar com acentos é sempre mais fácil, não é só uma questão de UX (para sites de múltiplos idiomas), é uma questão que tecnicamente dentro do sistema do site facilita (claro, se souber o que esta fazendo). Existe claro o modismo de falar que sempre devemos usar UTF-8 porque é melhor (mentira contada por um pessoal ai), em um site que não precisa de emoji e só acentos, latin1 (e equivalentes) vão resolver muito bem.

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta possui dois pontos, um objetivo, se há um impedimento técnico, e um mais subjetivo, o impacto na experiência do usuário.

Começando pelo mais simples, **há algum impedimento técnico?**

Hoje não, como havia comentado, já ouvi falar que, antigamente, não era possível (ou pelo menos não era viável) usar caracteres especiais em nomes de arquivos (um usuário mais velho pode confirmar isso), mas isso é um problema antigo, ainda há certos caracteres reservados, por exemplo, a `/` no Linux, mas acentos e até emojis são permitidos.

Não é uma limitação, mas um cuidado que se deve ter, se a codificação não estiver bem configurada, pode ocorrer de receber ou salvar arquivos com os caracteres `�`, `?`, `Ã©`, etc, o que pode levar a bugs e, claro, não é bom para o usuário.

Mesmo que, na URL do navegador mostre os caracteres especiais (nem todos), por baixo dos panos, eles são codificados antes da requisição ser feita. Obviamente uma URL como `pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-é-callback` não é válida, o navegador a codifica em `pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback`, alguns navegadores fazem essa conversão ([apesar do IE ter alguns problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391124)), mas a URL mostrada pro usuário é a codificada ([de novo o IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37303976)), mesmo nos principais navegadores há diferenças no que é mostrado na barra da URL, por exemplo, no Firefox, mostra o caracter espaço ( ), no Chrome mostra codificado (`%20`).

Alguns *parsers*, como do Stack Overflow, que identifica um trecho como sendo uma URL e o renderiza como um link (por exemplo, `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/` é transformado em `<a href="https://[...]" [...]>https://[...]</a>`) podem entender que certos caracteres especiais são um delimitador da URL fazendo com não seja exibido o desejado, como em [pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-](https://google.com/)é-callback (aqui estou forçando com o markdown).

Então, mesmo que não haja um problema concreto, há alguns cuidados que podem fazer com que a remoção faça sentido.

Indo agora pra parte mais subjetiva, **há impacto na experiência do usuário?**

Não impacta a remoção de acentos mantendo a letra sem acentuação, ou impacta muito pouco. Somos seres inteligentes (ou pelo menos deveríamos), então alguém que lê o texto "o-que-e-callback" entende que aquele "e" ali na verdade é um "é", já que o contexto ajuda.

Porém a remoção completa do caracter é ruim, principalmente em palavras pequenas. Mesmo em um contexto, muitos podem ter dificuldades e até não entender que, na URL `filmes.com/categorias/ao`, "ao" na verdade é "ação".

Dependendo do teu usuário não fará diferença, pessoas analfabetas (por exemplo, crianças em idade pré-escolar) obviamente não vão ler o link, apenas clicar pra então descobrir (ou não) do que se trata.

Em alguns casos específicos pode causar alguma confusão, semelhante ao caso das vírgulas mal/não utilizadas, por exemplo, `noticias.com/pais-sem-dinheiro` pode ser "pais sem dinheiro" (responsáveis legais) ou "país sem dinheiro" (pátria, nação). Outros casos específicos podem necessitar que mantenha o acento, por exemplo, um dicionário on-line terá as URLs `dicionario.com/esta` e `dicionario.com/está`, que se referem a palavras totalmente diferentes.

Comment: Tentei buscar referências que corroborem a parte subjetiva, apesar de até ter encontrado algo que me ajudou a responder, não era nada diretamente relacionado, no máximo algo sobre a SEO, problemas decorrentes e uso de caracteres não latinos